# In python SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.5.1. When I was trying this

```
print(r'\t\\\')
```

I got the error: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.
But this one worked well

```
print(r'\t\\')
```

Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 6):

See the 3.5 docs on [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the result; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (**even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes**). Specifically, *a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash* (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the literal, *not* as a line continuation.