# how do I know how many backslash to add in Python

Tags: python

> Why I need to add 5 backslash on the left if I want to show three of them in Python? How to count the backslash?

```
# [ ] print "\\\WARNING!///"
print('"\\\\\Warning///"')
```

Comment: \ is used for special characters like `'\n'`, `'\t'` etc... and so \ is coded as a special character as well as `'\\'`. So just double all your \. (It may work sometimes without doubling them, but it will work for sure if you always double them.)

Comment: Follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323050/in-python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal), it has good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is used for special characters like `'\n'`, `'\t'` etc. You should type `2n`  or  `2n-1`   `\` for printing  `n`   `\`.

```
>>> print('\warning') # 1 \
\warning
>>> print('\\warning') # 2 \
\warning
>>> print('\\\warning') # 3 \
\\warning
>>> print('\\\\warning') # 4 \
\\warning
>>> print('\\\\\warning') # 5 \
\\\warning
>>> print('\\\\\\warning') # 6 \
\\\warning
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "raw string" by adding `r`:

```
print(r'"\\\Warning///"')
```

This helps to avoid the backslash's "escape" properties, which python uses to control the use of special characters

Comment: raw strings don't necessarily work: `r"\"` is broken.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that... But it does work for multiple backspaces like OP wants

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is taken as escape sequence most of the time thus for printing single `\` one needs to use `\\`

Answer (score 1):

according to https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

> Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., the backslash is left in the string.

since `\W` is not a valid escape sequence, `\W` is printed as it is. on the other hand `\\` is printed as `\`.

so `\\\\\W` is printed as `\\\W`

However, in python 3.6, according to [Strings and bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

> Changed in version 3.6: Unrecognized escape sequences produce a DeprecationWarning. In some future version of Python they will be a SyntaxError.

So your code might give SyntaxError in future python.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike standard C, any unrecognized escape sequences are left unchanged in python.

```
>>> print('\test')
'    est'  # '\t' evaluates to tab + 'est'

>>> print('\\test')
'\test'  # '\\' evaluates to literal '\' + 'test'

>>> print('\\\test')
'\    est'  # '\\' evaluates to literal '\' + '\t' evaluates to tab + 'est'

>>> print('\\\\test')
'\\test'  # '\\' evaluates to literal '\' + '\\' evaluates to literal '\' + 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should type 2n backslashes to represent n of them, technically. In a strict grammar, backslash is reserved as an escape character and has a special meaning, i.e., it does not represent "backslash". So, we took it from our character set to give it a special meaning then how to represent a pure "backslash"? The answer is represent it in the way newline character is represented, namely '\' stands for a backslash.

And the reason why you get 3 backslashes printed when 5 is typed is: The first 4 of them is interpreted as I said above and when it comes to the fifth one, the interpreter found that there is no definition for '\W' so it treated the fifth backslash as a normal one instead of a escape character. This is an advanced convenience feature of the interpreter and might not be true in other versions of it or in other languages (especially in more strict ones).