# Raw strings containing Windows paths produce "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal"

Tags: python, syntax, string-literals

I am trying to use a shutil script I found but it receives `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 4)`. Any assistance would be appreciated to fixing this or new script

```
import shutil
import os

source = r"C:\Users\[username]\Downloads\"
dest1 = r" C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\Reports\14"
dest2 = r" C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\Reports\52"
dest3 = r" C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\Reports\59"

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
   
 if (f.startswith("Log 14")):
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
    elif (f.startswith("Log 54")):
        shutil.move(f, dest2)
```

Comment: **it is not working** is not something we can not help you with. Be more specific.

Comment: I had received SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 4) error.

Comment: You DO see the different colored rendering? that is partly because \" is interpreted ans escaping the " .. but you also have SLANTED " in your code. Fix it and try again.

Comment: Note that this is a new error message in Python 3.10. The old error message was `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` (at least as far back as 2.7).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323050/in-python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: I just noticed @John overhauled the question, which might be jarring for a newbie. The reason is that SO is meant for questions about specific technical problems, and questions that amount to ["Can someone help me?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341) are not helpful. So John changed the focus to the immediate problem. See [ask].

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea. That's exactly right. Ric, if you have additional problems I recommend you post a new question so that each post can be a single problem and its solution. Of course, try to debug them on your own first. It's best not to ask SO until you've given it the old college try yourself.

Comment: Some answers focus on smart quotes, which I think was a typo in OP. Thing is, with dumb quotes it still fails since a backslash before the closing quote is wonky. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash ... yes that's listed above, but there's another answer listed which is off the mark (as already answered links often are) ... ignore that other one

Answer (score 3):

You had smart quotes instead of normal ones. Indenting is also not correct.

Here is the fixed code:

```py
import shutil
import os

source = "C:\\Users\\[username]\\Downloads\\"
dest1 = "C:\\Users\\[username]\\Desktop\\Reports\\14"
dest2 = "C:\\Users\\[username]\\Desktop\\Reports\\52"
dest3 = "C:\\Users\\[username]\\Desktop\\Reports\\59"

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if f.startswith("Log 14"):
        shutil.move(source + f, dest1)
    elif f.startswith("Log 54"):
        shutil.move(source + f, dest2)
```

Comment: My bad that was a typo on my side, I have corrected it however, the script still unsuccessful. After running the script the files did not move and also did not received an error.

Comment: They worked correctly for me. Do your filenames start with the given strings? (Log 14, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for smart quotes `”`. They need to be double quotes `"`.

Comment: I think the smart quote was a typo in the question ... not the real issue. It fails even with dumb quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

if os.name == 'nt':    #check if windows 
  a='\\'
else:
  a='/'


source = "C:"+a+"Users"+a+"[username]"+a+"Downloads"+a
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: (Though note that Python is perfectly happy to use forward slashes as directory separators on Windows.)

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32192777)

Answer (score 0):

Smart Quotation Marks strike again.

Using [BabelStone](https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html), one can determine the unicode identification of each character in your code.

The start/ending quotes you're used to are `\U0022`. However, the end of the URL on `dest2` ends with a different character, which is `\U201D`. This is a different character. Easiest way to fix this is to retype out the quotation marks in your IDE.

Input: `"”`

```
U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK {double quote}
U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK {double comma quotation mark}
```